# Datagridview cell with background image

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I have created a DataGridView, one of the cells (DataGridViewTextBoxCell) I would like to have a background image. To do this I have used the following on the ***CellPainting*** event.

```
private void dataGridView1_CellPainting(object sender, DataGridViewCellPaintingEventArgs e)
    {
        var image = Resources.item_qty_white;
        e.PaintBackground(e.ClipBounds, false);

        e.Graphics.DrawImageUnscaled(image, 1410, e.CellBounds.Top);
    }
```

This works well and the image is on ever row in the position I want. However, the cell it is sitting in has a DataGridViewTextBoxCell with a numeric value. The image floats on top of this value and thus is hidden. I guess the ideal solution would be to make the DataGridViewTextBoxCell be "TopMost" but I couldn't figure out how to do this.

I then decided to try and make the background image partial transparent so the value underneath would be visual, so I changed my ***CellPainting*** code to below.

```
 private void dataGridView1_CellPainting(object sender, DataGridViewCellPaintingEventArgs e)
    {
        var image = Resources.item_qty_white;

        e.PaintBackground(e.ClipBounds, false);
        image.MakeTransparent(Color.White);
        e.Graphics.DrawImageUnscaled(image, 1410, e.CellBounds.Top);
    }
```

This again worked and I could see the value with the background image surrounding it as I would like. However the next issue arise when I tried to update the value of the cell. Once I did that the previous value was visible and the new value that I was trying to set was overlapping it. I am now stuck.

Any advice/guidance would be very appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to set `e.Handled = true` to prevent the system from painting. The below code works as you expected.

```
void dataGridView1_CellPainting(object sender, DataGridViewCellPaintingEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.RowIndex != -1 && e.ColumnIndex == columnIndex)
    {
        if ((e.PaintParts & DataGridViewPaintParts.Background) != DataGridViewPaintParts.None)
        {
            e.Graphics.DrawImage(Resources.Image1, e.CellBounds);                    
        }
        if (!e.Handled)
        {
            e.Handled = true;
            e.PaintContent(e.CellBounds);
        }            
    }
}
```