# Is it possible to add a background image to the top left header of dataGridView?

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I'm using `DataGridView` in WinForms. Is it possible to add a background image to the top left header of `DataGridView`? By top left header, I mean the header that selects the whole table by default if clicked.

I noticed `dataGridView.TopLeftHeaderCell.Style` exists, and it has a property for background color, but not for background image.

I also attempted to change it using the graphics property like below:

```
private void dataGridView1_CellPainting(object sender, DataGridViewCellPaintingEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.RowIndex==0 && e.ColumnIndex==0)
        {
            e.Graphics.DrawImage(myImage, e.CellBounds);
            e.Handled = true;
        }
    }
```

Unfortunately, `rowIndex == 0 && columnIndex == 0` does not represent the top left header cell, but rather the top left regular cell.

Comment: .NET is very flexible and virtually anything can be done. The problem is usually not if something can be done, but at what expense and if it is really worthy. You can modify the appearance and functionalities of any (default) control as much as you wish. On the other hand, most of people in SO don't feel like delivering codes perfectly meeting the expectations of the asker. Can you please show us what you have tried so far?

Comment: @varocarbas sorry, please see edits

Comment: Possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/q/22560105/3279496

Comment: No need to apologise. It is for you to get help quicker. Additionally in this case, you had the problem virtually solved. Sharing what you have is always a good idea.

Comment: Just change `if (e.RowIndex == 0 && e.ColumnIndex == 0)` to `if (e.RowIndex == -1 && e.ColumnIndex == -1)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem I was having was referring to the top left header cell becuase row 0 column 0 refer to the top left regular cell not header cell.

It can be done by referring to a row and column index lower than 0. See code below.

```
private void dataGridView1_CellPainting(object sender, DataGridViewCellPaintingEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.RowIndex<0 && e.ColumnIndex<0)
        {
            e.Graphics.DrawImage(myImage, e.CellBounds);
            e.Handled = true;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `DataGridView`'s `Paint` event to draw on the `DataGridView`:

```
private void dataGridView1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
{
    e.Graphics.DrawIcon(System.Drawing.SystemIcons.Exclamation, 
                        new Rectangle(0, 0, 16, 16));
}
```

This is an example using an icon. You can also use `e.Graphics.DrawImage`.

But you will need to adjust the image size to cover the area you want the background image to cover.

Answer (score 0):

Well, this seems a bit OT, but i`d like to mention the edit of your post.

> Unfortunately, rowIndex == 0 && columnIndex == 0 does not represent
>   the top left header cell, but rather the top left regular cell.

Please try the following:

`dataGridView1.TopLeftHeaderCell.Value = "123";`